# Can I set the font family for different elements of a plot in matplotlib using rc params and include it in a stylesheet?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to define a font family for the axis tick labels that is different from the plots font family? Additionally, can this be done with rc params and how would that look like in an rc params style sheet?

Plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('mpl.style')
plt.figure()
plt.title('Plot')
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
plt.show()
```

Style sheet

```
font.family : TeX Gyre Heros
# Is something like this possible
# axis.font.family : Deja Vu
```

Comment: I do not think is posible you can define a specific size the axes but not a different family

Comment: for font family, the answer is NO